# Beautifulsoup: can not select child

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following HTML and I need to get the content of tag:a, i.e "Nature" in this case:

```
<li class="tag">
    <a class="remove-tag" href="#">
        <i class="delete-tag" title="Delete"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#">Nature</a>
</li>
```

First I try to select 'li' with 'tag' class.

```
soup.findAll("all", {"class": "tag"})
```

How can I get the content of tag:a?

Comment: Content of tag:a? You mean the <i> tag?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the css selectors you may be familiar with.

```
>>> soup.select_one("li.tag a:nth-of-type(2)").text
u'Nature'
```

Comment: well, some of them anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do a findAll on the soup it will find no need of traversing.

```
soup.findAll("a", {"class": "classname"})
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `soup.findAll("li", {"class": "tag"})[0].a`, which is:

```
<a class="remove-tag" href="#">
<i class="delete-tag" title="Delete"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

```
lis = soup.find_all('li', class_='tag')
data_rows=lis.findAll('a')
data=[data_rows[i].getText() for i in range(len(data_rows))]
```

*Don't forget to let us know if it solved your problem :)*